# How to conditionally add routes in React.JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-router, firebase-authentication

I have a login system with Firebase and I want to dynamically add routes if someone enters correct information, I want it to add the main route and the add route.

```
var userToken = 'firebase:authUser:AIzaSyDfC9LqfL1rbClhfCOD04BKC9ZIn7UAZ_g:[DEFAULT]';

ReactDOM.render(
    <Router history={hashHistory}>
        <Route path="/" component={Login} />
        <Route path="signup" component={Signup} />
         { localStorage.getItem(userToken) ? (
            <Route path="main" component={Main} />
          ) : (<Redirect from="main" to="/" />)
        }
        { localStorage.getItem(userToken) ? (
            <Route path="add" component={Add} />
          ) : null
        }  
        <Route path="main" component={Main} />
        <Route path="*" component={NotFound} />
    </Router>
    , document.getElementById('container'));
```

The code above is working fine, but it has a flaw when someone types the correct information, they have to reload the page and enter the information again to log in.

Is there any way around where they don't have to reload the page after successful authentication?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd suggest creating components `SecureMain` and `SecureAdd` and updating the routes to use those instead. These would check for the existence of the user token and render either the desired content, or your `NotFound` component otherwise. For example (note that I banged this out as a concept and it may not be perfect):

```
import React from 'react';
import Main from './Main';
import NotFound from './NotFound';

export default class SecureMain extends React.Component {
  constructor(...args) {
    super(...args);
    this.state = { token: localStorage.getItem(userToken) };
  }
  render() {
    if (this.state.token) return <Main {...this.props} />;
    else return <NotFound {...this.props} />;
  }
}
```

This makes the state of your application much easier to predict based on its state.

Of course I also have to echo **@ZekeDroid**'s disclaimer about client-side "security":

[image: client-side security IRL]

Answer (score 3):

That's an interesting approach at authentication. Very interesting. My suggestion is for you to add Redux or straight up to wrap your `Router` in a parent component. This way, when the user triggers what I assume is some `onChange` handler, it should update that parent's state rather than `localStorage` only. At that point, that parent will re-render its children (in your case, the `Router`) hence generating new `Routes`!

Disclaimer: it's still easy to get around this authentication since anyone can go to the source and change the line to read `{ true ? <Route path="add" component={Add} /> : null }`, but still, kinda cool approach.

Comment: So don't do this for security reasons, but for usability reasons :-)

Comment: pointing at your "Disclaimer", though we can get around this authentication but when using the component to Add something i think there must be a verification of authenticity of the user on the server side ?

Comment: sure, but unless the server is the one re-routing then it's still unsafe